# How to range over files but skip one specific filename

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm working on some blog code (written by someone else) which lists all posts into the main index.html file. I want to exclude one file (welcome.md) from this listing. I believe this is the relevant code that does this -

```
{{$l := len .}}
{{range $i, $e := .}}         
<h3><a href="/{{$e.Title | slug}}.html">{{$e.Title}}</a></h3>
```

Is it possible?

Update - Here is my full code, I left some out of the above -

```
{{define "title"}}
  Test
{{end}}

{{define "content"}}
<h1>Heading</h1>

{{$l := len .}}
      {{range $i, $e := .}}
      {{- if ne $e.Title "welcome" -}}        
            <h3><a href="/{{$e.Title | slug}}.html">{{$e.Title}}</a></h3>
            {{- end }}
            <small>
              <em>
              {{$e.Written.Format "Jan 2, 2006"}}&nbsp;
              Tags:  {{range $e.Tags}}
              <a href="/tags/{{. | slug}}.html" title="Posts Tagged {{.}}">{{.}}</a>&nbsp;
                {{end}}
              </em>
            </small>
            {{(printf "%s </br><small>[Read more](/%s.html)</small>" ($e.Content | summary) (.Title | slug)) | html}}

{{end}}
{{end}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{{if ...}}` in templates. Combine with the `ne` function (for "not equal"):

```
{{range $i, $e := .}}
  {{- if ne $e.Title "welcome" -}}
<h3><a href="/{{$e.Title}}.html">{{$e.Title}}</a></h3>
  {{- end }}
{{ end }}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/qumQ2MFpkRR)

However, it feels like maybe you can make it more general purpose if you have control over the data model. Perhaps a flag on each post for `ExcludeFromIndex` or something like that:

```
{{- if !$e.ExcludeFromIndex -}}
```

That way if you add more "special" pages you won't need to keep adding if statements for each one. Just an idea.

Comment: I like your second suggestion, but I just tried your first, and I'm getting an error - `ERROR: Failed to create generator: template: index.tmpl:10: illegal number syntax: "-"`

Comment: I added my full code, with your suggestion, to my first post so it may be easier to see why the error occurred.

Comment: Regarding your second idea, I will need to prevent listing of more than one file in the future. I didn't write the code so I don't have access to it but it is on github but I'm not a coder so...I was thinking a very simple way might be to see if the filename begins with `p-` which I would add for any post I want to be a page only. So would it look something like this - `{{- if ne $e.Title "p-*" -}}` ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had to remove the hyphens and move {{end}} down to the bottom like so -

```
{{$l := len .}}
      {{range $i, $e := .}}
      {{ if ne $e.Title "Welcome" }}
            <h3><a href="/{{$e.Title | slug}}.html">{{$e.Title}}</a></h3>
            <small>
              <em>
              {{$e.Written.Format "Jan 2, 2006"}}&nbsp;
              Tags:  {{range $e.Tags}}
              <a href="/tags/{{. | slug}}.html" title="Posts Tagged {{.}}">{{.}}</a>&nbsp;
                {{end}}
              </em>
            </small>
            {{(printf "%s </br><small>[Read more](/%s.html)</small>" ($e.Content | summary) (.Title | slug)) | html}}
        {{ end }}
{{end}}
{{end}}
```